# Just my application can access my database on localcdb

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, distributed, localdb

I have c# application that use sqllocaldb, application database is in attached mode and i want disturbing the application. 
I need to ensure no other applications can access my database and although no body can access it with ssms.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Check "always encrypted" but I don't know if it is supported with localdb too.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It sounds like you want an embedded database and localdb is not appropriate for that.

Comment: Always encrypted just encrypt data transfer between client and server or localdb, my problem is preventing access my database from any other connections or open it with ssms, for mire details, if i have mdf and ldf besides my application some other one can install any type of sql server such a express edition and then attached db to express and open my db

Comment: @Soroush Nobody can connect to your localdb unless you open file access. [See Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017#permissions) . Also, nobody hears you unless you address someone with @<username>

Comment: @Crowcider thanks for your both suggestions, suppose you develop a application that store your data in localdb with attached database and then i buy it and installing on my pc, now more than your application that can access db, i can develop an outher application and use your application data stored in db, or i can install ssms and attach your application db to my localdb instancs and access to your app saved data.

Comment: @Soroush you simply would not package your data files with the application or you would only package an empty or sample set of data.